# localhost redirect to other site... trojan?

Tags: localhost, trojan

As title, seems there's a trojan on my server
When I put a url like

localhost/mysite

it redirect to the site free-merchants.com and then return to my site...

But if I put

127.0.0.1/mysite

all work correctly...

Then, what is? I scan with avast and malwarebytes and no virus... 

With HijackThis I can't see any strange thing...
File hosts have only row

127.0.0.1 localhost

Can be a bug of my webserver that run with

Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) PHP/5.4.32

Or what I must scan?

Comment: Not a bad question, but IMO should be asked on SuperUser.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know SuperUser... Now I have posted also on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JRT (junkware removal tool) and Adware-removal tool (from techsupportall)
these 2 programs are wonderful to discover PUP, just an addition to malware bytes which is already excellent.

Comment: No malware with both software

Comment: did you try already checking in installed programs for it? try go control panel/uninstall a program and check if there's something related to free-merchants (or more in general try cleaning useless tools you might have installed). Probably it is not a PUP but an actual (annoying) program

Comment: No, there's nothing about this "program"...
I'm very meticulous about this...
Now I'm working on my backup/server with debian but when I'm out of my home, I must use my notebook with windows...
I can override the problem with 127.0.0.1 but I must/want resolve...

Comment: I would check chrome/firefox plugins or settings, because sometimes these PUP doesn't get removed by those tools. I do not know why. sometimes I need to manually clean the windows registry or look on google for that particular program and how to remove from chrome/firefox advanced settings. Also, chrome use settings of Iexplorer so try checking here as well for bad settings

Comment: Thanks at all... The problem was an extension... Disabled it and resolved...

More info here http://superuser.com/questions/1027995/localhost-redirect-to-other-site-trojan

Answer (score 2):

It seems like a unwanted change by a trojan or such...

check your hosts-file for malicious entries.
(ref.: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file) )

Comment: My host file contains only these rows

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
127.0.0.1         localhost
# ::1              localhost

Answer (score 0):

For me it was JQuery Debugger Extension:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jquery-debugger/dbhhnnnpaeobfddmlalhnehgclcmjimi?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog

Answer (score 0):

For me it's was Translation Selection Extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/translate-selection/goanabmlmgfinmjohhepcpffcnkeobjm. When I deleted this extension, all works fine

Answer (score 0):

We caught an infected Chrome Reloader Extension:
http://howtoremove.guide/remove-auto-refresh-plus-chrome-firefox/

:-(

Answer (score 0):

For me it was the Chomemarks extension.