# How to use htaccess to redirect link to subfolder

Tags: .htaccess

On my development machine my project is located at localhost/myproject. Something weird has been happening lately. Every time I type localhost/myproject/user/home.php, I get redirected to a total stranger's site at bookmark.com.

Couple people seem to have run to a similar problem in this [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1027995/localhost-redirect-to-other-site-trojan) and this other [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34855562/localhost-redirect-to-other-site-trojan) which appears to be the same.

So I did everything suggested... Removed all extensions, check the hosts files, ran all possible malwares antivirus, checked if my DNS was compromised...

Nothing worked for me. And everything seems fine. I even restored my pc to a previous working point in time... Still the problem persists when I'm trying to access the user folder.

Is there a way I could rewrite the path with .htaccess? What do you suggest I do?

Comment: Is your web server running on port 80? And by this I mean 1) if it is running, and 2) if it is listening on port 80.

Comment: @Juan: yes it is. Well it's 80,443.

Comment: Are you using the Apache document root or are you running a virtual server on a different folder.

Comment: @Juan: I'm running DOS by the way. I guess that would be the root. I'm using xampp. Right?

Comment: Do you get the same result if instead of localhost you use http : / / 127.0.0.1?

Comment: @Juan: Just tried 127.0.0.1/myproject/user/home.php and yes same result `:-(`

Comment: Do you have anything relevant in the server's log file.

Comment: @Juan: Sorry went to bed last night it was getting really late in my country. This is the last line in the logs `127.0.0.1 - - [16/May/2018:23:10:03 -0400] "GET /myproject/user/home.php HTTP/1.1" 302 18575 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0"`. As you can see there's HTTP 302 which is a url redirection.

Comment: @Juan: I think they're simply modifying my header.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171250/discussion-between-juan-and-javanoob).